Large rotation Euler-Bernoulli beam solving
Wikipedia and Jang give the following equation for an Euler-Bernoulli beam with uniform cross-section, no axial load, distributed netload and for moderately large deflections:
$$EI\frac{d^4u}{dx^4}-\frac{3}{2}EA\left(\frac{du}{dx}\right)^2\frac{d^2u}{dx^2} = q(x)$$
My goal is to solve this equation for a simply supported beam of length $L$ and constant load $q$. I further assume the following boundary conditions are true:
$$u(0)=u(L) = 0 \text{ and } u''(0)=u''(L) = 0$$
How do I solve this? Just try some MATLAB ODE-solvers? How can I know I got a good solution, just compare it to classical Euler-Bernoulli theory? Is there any semi-analytical approach to it? Any literature? I must admit my mathematical skills are limited, so I cannot really understand if Jang gives an approach which I can use for my problem, as the beam there is infinite and on foundation.
Edit: I found Akbari, which has probably an error in the equation ($EI$ instead of $EA$ in eq. (16)). There the equation is solved semi-analytically with an 8th  order polynomial. However, I suspect, that there is another approach. So my question remains.
